# Magento: Admin Content Configuration gives error handle not registered design_config_listing_data_source

Tags: admin, update-handle

When I opens the Magento 2 Admin-> Content -> Configuration it through an error Not registered handle design_config_listing_data_source
And it exists in both etc/di.xml and also added in design_config_listing.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that defined data-source already in -> etc/di.xml

But data-source is not defined in Adminhtml/di.xml

So just add data-source in etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                 <item name="design_config_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Magento\Theme\Model\ResourceModel\Design\Config\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
         </arguments>
</type>
```

This solves the issue and not Configurations page works fine in Magento admin -> contents

Comment: That does it. But wondering why it was working just fine until now and what caused it to report missing data provider? Apparently this issue started popping up after I temporarily edited `\Magento\Theme\Ui\Component\Design\Config\DataProvider` to add some debugging code. Ran `setup:di:compile` afterwards and saw the error for the first time.